# Fetching in Javascript in Service Worker

Tags: javascript, fetch, service-worker

I am currently trying use a service worker fetch event, with the fetch API to send a request to the server and get HTML back.  The issue I am running into involves POST requests.  When I try to do this when there is a POST, I am losing all the headers in the POST request (data needs to be added to the server for the posts).  I am trying to manually grab the headers and add them into the fetch, but without any luck.  Here is my current code for the fetch event:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {

    var acceptHeader = event.request.headers.get('Accept');
    //fetch options used for post requests
    var fetchOptionsForPost = {
        method: "post",
        headers: event.request.headers,
        credentials: event.request.credentials
    }


    //if it's a post request, 
    if( acceptHeader.indexOf('text/html') > -1 && event.request.method == "POST" ) {    
        var updatedFetch = fetch( event.request, fetchOptionsForPost).then(function(updatedResponse) {
            //do something with response here.
        });
    }
});
```

Update:

Gave crdumoul's suggestion a shot and gives the following console error:

```
ServiceWorker.js:52 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': Cannot construct a Request with a Request whose mode is 'navigate' and a non-empty RequestInit.
    at TypeError (native)
    at [URL to service worker]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method to "POST" instead of "post" in fetchOptionsForPost.

Comment: Gave that a shot, with the following error:

ServiceWorker.js:52 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': Cannot construct a Request with a Request whose mode is 'navigate' and a non-empty RequestInit.
    at TypeError (native)
    at [URL to service worker]

Comment: Try setting "mode" to "no-cors" in fetchOptionsForPost. Also, you could try creating a new Request for the fetch, instead of just passing in an init object with the original Request.

Comment: I did try adding the "no-cors" and a new request for the fetch.  But the server is responding with "malformed data" error now.